# What is the best way to optimize xslt transforms in exist-db?

Tags: xml, xslt, exist-db

I have an eXist database that I'm rendering to html through a single xql that calls to an xslt page, via this block of code:

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";
declare namespace m = "http://www.minorworksoflydgate.net/model";
declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "xhtml";
declare option output:media-type "application/xhtml+xml";
declare option output:omit-xml-declaration "no";
declare option output:html-version "5.0";
declare option output:indent "no";
declare option output:include-content-type "no";

declare variable $exist:root as xs:string := 
    request:get-parameter("exist:root", "xmldb:exist:///db/apps");
declare variable $exist:controller as xs:string := 
    request:get-parameter("exist:controller", "/mwjl-app");


declare variable $text := request:get-data(); (:this variable allows the pipeline to work:)
let $xsl := xs:anyURI($exist:root || $exist:controller || "/data/stylesheets/wrapper.xsl")
return
    transform:transform($text, $xsl, ())
```

To transform a TEI XML page, the bulk of which is a list formatted like this:

```
<list type="index">
    <item n="draft" xml:id="6561"><emph rend="italic">A lamentacioun of our lady Maria</emph>
        <ref target="http://www.dimev.net/record.php?recID=6561">(DIMEV: 6561)</ref> 
    </item>
    <list>
        <item>
            <ref target="/Quis_Dabit/Jesus_College_Q_G_8/Jesus_Q_G_8_f19v.html">Cambridge, Jesus College Q.G.8</ref>
        </item>
        <item><ref
            target="/Quis_Dabit/British_Library_Harley_2251/British_Library_Harley_2251_f42v.html"
            >London, British Library Harley 2251</ref></item>
        <item><ref
            target="/Quis_Dabit/British_Library_Harley_2255/British_Library_Harley_2255_f66v.html"
            >London, British Library Harley 2255</ref></item>
        <item><ref target="/Quis_Dabit/Laud_683/Laud_683_f78r.html">Oxford, Bodleian
            Library Laud misc. 683</ref></item>
        <item><ref target="/Quis_Dabit/St_John_56/St_John_56_73v.html">Oxford, St.
            John's College 56</ref></item>
    </list>
    <item n="draft" xml:id="747"><emph rend="italic">A Mumming at Eltham</emph><ref
        target="http://www.dimev.net/record.php?recID=747"> (DIMEV:
        747)</ref></item>
    <list>
        <item><ref target="/Mumming_Eltham/Trinity_R_3_20/Trinity_R_3_20_f19r.html"
            >Cambridge, Trinity College R.3.20</ref></item>
        <item><ref
            target="/Mumming_Eltham/British_Library_Additional_29729/Add_29729_f135v.html"
            >London, British Library Addit. 29729</ref></item>
    </list>
</list>
```

This works, but on a few of my pages the xml, which I created out of what was originally a set of SQL results, is noticeably slow if it gets over 8000 lines. Much more so than a straight Saxon transformation into html would be. It's a single xml page, so indexing does not seem to do much. How do I optimize the xql to render the page quickly, or am I better off just setting eXist aside?

ETA: The xsl for this particular bit is as follows. It's not the entirety of the xsl files -- those are split between a file for the header and a file for the body in a wrapper file that the xql calls to -- but it might help.

The wrapper file is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:teix="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/Examples" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:rng="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#default html a fo rng tei teix" version="3.0">

    
    <xsl:include href="header.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="body.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The germane bit of the body.xsl (the header.xsl file is rendered on pages that load fine so I don't think it is the issue) is as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:list">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@rend='ordered'">
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ol>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type='index'">
            <ul class="index">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type='simple'">
            <ul class="nodisplay">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@xml:id='compare'">
            <ul class="nodisplay">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type='bibliography'">
            <ul class="nodisplay bibliography">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:list[@xml:id = 'bullet_list']/tei:item">
    <li>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:text>bullet_list</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="tei:item">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@xml:id">
            <li>
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@xml:id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
                        <xsl:text>anchor</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </a>
            </li>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <li>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </li>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I think the issue is the number of list/items combinations the code is iterating through, but I'm not sure how you resolve that if an index doesn't work and given the way xsl handles a document.

Comment: It might be helpful to see the XSLT and see what could possibly be optimized.

Comment: It's pretty long, as it handles more than just the pages this is going on with.  I'll edit the post to add the bit for this list/item ref section though if that'll help.

Comment: A very generic answer: the only way to optimize anything is to measure, measure, measure. Saying it's "noticeably slow" when it reaches 8000 lines is a start, but only a small start. Try to measure how the actual performance varies with document size. Is it linear or quadratic? The more accurate data you can get on measured performance, the closer you are to a solution.